# I can neither access nor recover my account

Tags: support

I had an old account on Stack Exchange and I cannot access it any more. I searched my old emails and found mails from Stack Overflow so I know that this is the email address I used for the account. But still, if I try to recover my account, it says that the email address is unknown.

Comment: Did you have any questions with answers on this account? Any answers?

Answer (score 7):

E-mail team@stackoverflow.com with as much information has you have:

- The e-mail address you used.
- Links to any questions and/or answers you posted using that account.
- Dates when you used the account.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you're using the right recovery service. There's a separate OpenID service we provide than our actual Q&A site accounts. If you had an account from way back, it's likely you didn't create it with our OpenID and instead used a different one.

Use https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery for recovering an account on Stack Overflow.

Use https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/recovery for recovering a Stack Exchange OpenID account.

Comment: Ok thank you! This link http://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery worked. I got an email saying "Log in using these credentials on the login page." However, it only shows my email address, no password. If I go to the login page, how do I recover my password now? If I click on "click here to recover your account" it takes me to https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/recovery which does not know my email address.